# Yii - Does database dependency caching work across multiple actions?

Tags: caching, yii

Take this piece of code as an example:

```
public function actionPostOneWay( $postId )
{
    $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency( 'SELECT publish_date FROM posts WHERE id = :post_id;' );
    $dependency->params = array( 'post_id'=>$postId );
    $post = Post::model()->cache( 59, $dependency )->findByPk( $postId );

    // process post one way
}

public function actionPostAnotherWay( $postId )
{
    $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency( 'SELECT publish_date FROM posts WHERE id = :post_id;' );
    $dependency->params = array( 'post_id'=>$postId );
    $post = Post::model()->cache( 59, $dependency )->findByPk( $postId );

    // process post another way
}
```

So will accessing `/postOneWay` and `/postAnotherWay` reuse the same cached object, or will they create cache objects of their own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to cache the same query in two different actions and yes, the same cached object will be used. One can see that enabling `CProfileLogRoute` in application's configuration file.

Looking at the source code of `CActiveRecord` class I stated that `public function findByPk($pk,$condition='',$params=array())` method (and other query methods) use `protected function query($criteria,$all=false)`. This one, in turn, finally relies on `private function queryInternal($method,$mode,$params=array())` of `CDbCommand` class where Yii makes its caching work with database queries.

As one can see a cache key used to store and restore queries' results is defined as follows:

```
$cacheKey='yii:dbquery'.$this->_connection->connectionString.':'.$this->_connection->username;
$cacheKey.=':'.$this->getText().':'.serialize(array_merge($this->_paramLog,$params));
if(($result=$cache->get($cacheKey))!==false)
{
    Yii::trace('Query result found in cache','system.db.CDbCommand');
    return $result;
}
```

This key doesn't take a cache dependency instance into consideration. `CDbCacheDependency` is only used to determine whether something is changed in database and new query is to be executed to update the cache. To say more - if you specify different SQLs to create `CDbCacheDependency` in two actions only one of them (executed first) will make sense during caching time due to the instance of `CDbCacheDependency` is cached serialized along with query's result:

```
if(isset($cache,$cacheKey))
    $cache->set($cacheKey, $result, $this->_connection->queryCachingDuration, $this->_connection->queryCachingDependency);
```

Caching an instance of evaluated dependency could be seen in `public function set($id,$value,$expire=0,$dependency=null)` method of `CCache` class:

```
if ($dependency !== null && $this->serializer !== false)
    $dependency->evaluateDependency();

if ($this->serializer === null)
    $value = serialize(array($value,$dependency));
elseif ($this->serializer !== false)
    $value = call_user_func($this->serializer[0], array($value,$dependency));
```

Comment: Wow! Wasn't expecting this level of detail. Thanks! Most of it makes sense. I am confused about this line: "if you specify different SQLs to create CDbCacheDependency in two actions only one of them (executed first) will make sense during caching time due to the instance of CDbCacheDependency is cached serialized along with query's result". Do you mean to say that the dependency instance is being cached and reused?

Comment: Yes, I meant this exactly. Dependency instance will be cached with the value, and next time when cache value is to be retrieved in `if(($result=$cache->get($cacheKey))!==false)` condition this instance will be used to determine whether some changes occured in database executing dependency's query and comparing the result with the one evaluated before (when cache value was set). You can test it by yourself adding `CProfileLogRoute` to `log` component of application's configuration and setting `enableProfile` flag of `db` component to `true`.